# Path Display at bottom of a Finder window in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, finder

I have seen "A status bar like tray at the bottom which displays the path of a directory" in  Finder window.

How do I turn that on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

View » Show Path Bar

Comment: So Easy, I didn't even notice it. Thank You.